# Facebook like button - control meta info

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

Is it possible to control the meta information (Title, description, etc) dynamically?

I want a user to be able to "Like/share" a url, but I want to customize the meta information.

My software allows a user to make a reservation online for a restaurant and I want the user to be able to like the URL of the restaurant, but with custom information.
ex:
I just made a reservation at XXXXXXX.

Instead of using the meta tags of the URL that is being liked.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that's possible. You have to own a page to set its Open Graph meta data. Otherwise Likes that show up on user profiles could be very misleading.

Answer (score 0):

I just did some research regarding this and I can confirm it's not possible. You need to own that specific **public** URL and fill meta information. However, it's possible to solve this by creating and serving specific (RESTful) URLs for specific items.